# Parameterized PreparedStatement for QUERY_BAND in Teradata JDBC

Tags: java, spring, teradata, jdbctemplate

When using QUERY_BAND whith paramitrized PreparedStatement, i got this exception :

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.04] [Error 5992] [SQLState HY000] A syntax error was found in the QUERY_BAND.
```

My code :

```
 String queryBand = "SET QUERY_BAND = ? UPDATE FOR SESSION VOLATILE;";
 try {
 dbConnection = baseJDBCTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
        //set user name in the Query Band
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(queryBand)) {
            stmt.setString(1, "USER=x256;");//"+rtId+"
            stmt.execute(queryBand);
        }
 catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new SIRRestitGeneratorException("DB Exception ",e);
 }
```

i did the same thing recomanded n Teradata documentation
https://docs.teradata.com/r/eWpPpcMoLGQcZEoyt5AjEg/RH2BOZYzHp6u4dhsrWbRlw

i'm using
Teradata version 16.20.00.04
Spring Boot 1.5.8

Comment: Don't... Just use the `JdbcTemplate` you already have to execute the code. Your code is flawed as it leaks a connection. Just do `jdbcTemplate.update` to execute the query.

Comment: Thank your response, but i'm getting exception in this line try (PreparedStatement stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(queryBand)) { before the execution line

Comment: Regardless you still should use the jdbcTemplate and not in the way you are using it now. Do something like `baseJdbcTemplate.update(queryBand, "USER=x256");`. Nothing more nothing less and ditch everything else.

Comment: i got the same issue [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.04] [Error 5992] [SQLState HY000] A syntax error was found in the QUERY_BAND.

Comment: Is that `UPDATE FOR SESSION VOLATILE` valid?

Comment: Yes, when i remove the ? parameter, it work fine, String queryBand = "SET QUERY_BAND = 'USER=xxx;' UPDATE FOR SESSION VOLATILE;";

Comment: The problem is that `update` uses `executeUpdate` and not `execute`. Try the execute method with a `PreparedStatementCalback`. Then do `setString` and `execute`.

Comment: Don't pass the `"SET QUERY_BAND = ? UPDATE FOR SESSION VOLATILE;"` string as an argument to PreparedStatement execute method. That makes this statement text the parameter value which replaces the `?`. EIther use `setString` first and pass no parameters or just pass the `"USER=x256"` as the parameter in `execute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the response in this doc
https://docs.teradata.com/r/rgAb27O_xRmMVc_aQq2VGw/oXcSulxgPuaDnG0qMLYYrg

The ? parameter is not supported for SESSION, it's supported only for TRANSACTION.

```
String queryBand = "SET QUERY_BAND=? UPDATE FOR SESSION VOLATILE;"; // not accepted

String queryBand = "SET QUERY_BAND=? UPDATE FOR TRANSACTION;"; // accepetd
```

So in my case (updating the session), i can't use the ? parameter, so i use this (even i have sonar security alert):

```
String queryBand = "SET QUERY_BAND='USER="+StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(rtfeId)+";' UPDATE FOR SESSION VOLATILE;";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the `JdbcTemplate` you are using it wrong, and dangerous as this leaks a connection, when executed enough times, it will grind your app to a hold.

Use the `JdbcTemplate` in a proper way.

```java
jdbcTemplate.execute(queryBand, (ps) -> {
  ps.setString(1, "USER=x256");
  return ps.execute();
});
```

This should execute your query and return a `boolean` if it succeeded or not. Which of course you can ignore if you don't need that.

With this you are properly utilizing the `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: The Teradata JDBC Driver does not offer a "QueryBand" connection parameter. https://downloads.teradata.com/forum/database/set-queryband-as-jdbc-connection-parameter, i think that parameter is not accepted, and documentation here is not up to date https://docs.teradata.com/r/scPHvjfglIlB8F70YliLAw/~KvKWLm6JQ5lDYCgKW5zVA

Comment: This has nothing to do with the JDBC drivers properties or parameters, but on what the server accepts.

Comment: finally it's not supported for SESSION, it's only supported for TRANSACTION